# Build Jython Err: "NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/Tool"

Tags: ant, antlr, jython, jython-2.5

I tried to build Jython on my macbook pro, but got an error after simpley `ant` command.

```
$ jython-2.5.4-rc1-sources zzhao$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/jack/Dev/jython/jython-2.5.4-rc1-sources/build.xml

init:

needed-check:

clean-if-antlr-needed:

init:

clean-checkout-dir:

clean:

prepare-output:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jack/Dev/jython/jython-2.5.4-rc1-sources/build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jack/Dev/jython/jython-2.5.4-rc1-sources/build/gensrc/org/python/antlr
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jack/Dev/jython/jython-2.5.4-rc1-sources/build/exposed
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jack/Dev/jython/jython-2.5.4-rc1-sources/dist

antlr_gen:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/Tool
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.Tool
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

BUILD FAILED
/Users/jack/Dev/jython/jython-2.5.4-rc1-sources/build.xml:496: Java returned: 1
```

Any idea to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your build is failing in the "antlr_gen" target. The java task is missing the antlr jar from its classpath.

Can't help any further without an ANT build.xml to debug.